# Android application crash when add advertising

Tags: android

I am on the last step for my android app: I would like to add a banner. My application works fine without a banner but there's a crash with (when I open the app with the banner I have the message "my app has stopped"). So I try to add a banner on a very simple app like HelloWorld below to see where the error is, but I have the same type of error when I open the app , although it works perfectly fine without... Here's my MainActivity (nothing special for a hello world ...).

```
package com.example.publicite;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here's my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="my ID for the bann generated by admob"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/votrescore"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="..." />
```

and here's my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.publicite"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.publicite.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"                                     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I see other message on stackoverflow for my problem. I programme "above" api13 (that is important for advertising) and I downloaded the googlemobileadsandroidsdk.zip (version 6.4.1). I add this as an external jar and I tick this in "order and export". It seems that there's is no error (all is green in log cat). Well I'm confused. Thanks !

Comment: I have any new error when I launch the app as android application.

Comment: Are you using android studio with gradle?

Comment: Failed to load properties file for project 'publicite' but this error dates is 13h42 and actually it is 18h19 ...

Comment: I don't know if I use gradle. I am using eclipse and my smarpthone is my "emulator"

Comment: make sure your using the latest play service library. I don't see any error in the xml

Comment: excuse me but i'm a newbie ^^ what do you mean by the latest pplay service library ? I download android 3.2 (api 13) . Should I have to download the very latest version (api19) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using the Google Ads library (GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-x.x.x.jar) then you have to use.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView>
```

and if your using Google Play then

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Note this :**

Deprecated. On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower. You must upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK by then.

Comment: I'm using:6.4.1  GoogleMobileAdsSdkAndroid.zip

Comment: No there's still the problem, although I use now <com.google.ads.AdView> in my xml. I also use now android:name="com.google.android.ads.AdActivity" in my manifest

Comment: By the way what is the difference between google ads library and google play service ? I just want a banner with advertising on it

Comment: Ok i just see the difference between the two services on an other stack topic. I wil remove the 6.4.1 and i will use google play service instead. I will mention you if it works.

Comment: To use all the Google Service ApI's you need to use Google Play Service SDK. The latest Google Play service version included the Ads API in it.

Comment: Ok, but it should also work with the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-x.x.x.jar as per the document. check this link https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?hl=it#play

Comment: Thanks my app doesn't crash any more ! But I have an other problem now ("required xml attribute "adSize" was missing") ^^. Don't find the solution... I will create a specific topic for this ;)